# SOQL Query to Export Opportunities missing specific contact role

Tags: soql

I'm a total novice at writing SOQL queries and need some help defining a query to export all opportunities which are missing a specific contact role.

I need to identify all opportunities without a Contact Role where Role = 'Donor'.

Here's my non-working query:

```
    SELECT Id, Amount, CloseDate, Name, StageName, cv__Contact__r.FirstName, cv__Contact__r.LastName 
    FROM Opportunity
    WHERE Donor NOT IN (
        SELECT Role
        FROM OpportunityContactRole
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track by using a construct called a *semi-join* here (`WHERE ... NOT IN (SELECT ...)`). However, what you need to do here is query based on the Opportunity Id, because that's the field that links together the Opportunity Contact Role and the Opportunity itself.

The way you'd do that here is

```
SELECT Id, Amount, CloseDate, Name, StageName, cv__Contact__r.FirstName, cv__Contact__r.LastName 
FROM Opportunity
WHERE Id NOT IN (
    SELECT OpportunityId
    FROM OpportunityContactRole
    WHERE Role = 'Donor'
)
```

The key is that `Id`, on the Opportunity, and `OpportunityId`, on the Opportunity Contact Role, have the same type - they're both, well, Opportunity Ids - and you can therefore do a join on them here. You use a `WHERE` clause in your subquery to define the specific set of records you're looking to exclude.

More information at the [SOQL and SOSL Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm#semijoin_and_antijoin).